# How reference managed code from Silverlight 4/5

Tags: silverlight

I am writing a Silverlight 4 (could be 5) app that will run out of browser.

I need to load data from a SQL CE database and also reference GIS data that are both stored on a local drive.

The code to do both of these things will be stored in a separate data access layer assembly as it will be shared with other solutions.

How do I use the DAL assembly from the Silverlight project? Do I have to go down the P/Invoke route or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RickNZ is correct. A Silverlight app can't access a non-Silverlight library (unless its a [portable library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx)) nor can they access local files without the user uploading them. I n my opinion, the following is your list practical options:

- Rewrite the DAL in Silverlight
- Create a simple Soap or Rest service for the DAL and have the Silverlight app access it that way
- Stick with WPF and convert your other applications to WPF as well (if they are also OOB)

Converting from Silverlight to WPF is typically very is since Silverlight is more or less a subset WPF. Of course this might not be an option if the other two apps are not OOB apps.

If you want to stick with Silverlight, then I would suggest writing a quick Rest service to sit on top of your DAL so your applications can access it.

**Note:** As per SteveChadbourne's correction, you can use platform invocation, but only in Silverlight 5. As soon as your application makes use of this new feature, it must be run as a full-trust application on a Windows machine.

Comment: I like the rest service idea. Be aware though that SL5 does allow you to access a non-SL library. http://bit.ly/pBe8z3

Comment: Wow, wouldn't have ever thought they would have added that. I haven't looked into 5 yet, but it seems as though I should.

Comment: I have always thought platform invocation was strictly for win32 api calls (unmanaged code). Most definitions of it tend to state this, but never actually say it can't be used to call managed APIs. This is probably because nobody ever needed to until Silverlight 5 added support just recently.

Comment: That is my problem - I don't want to be forced into mangling my managed code so it can be used in a native code fashion. That takes me down the COM route and I don't really want to go there! Surely there must be a better way.

Comment: From your initial description, it doesn't seem like your DAL is doing anything more than data look-up. Because of this, and the fact that its a Silverlight app, I still think you should make a simple rest service for the DAL and that way the app doesn't have to be tied to the same computer. There are plenty of tutorials on this subject if you don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference and include additional DLLs with your Silverlight project. However, be aware that the .NET runtime for Silverlight is not the same as the "regular" .NET runtime, so there are some substantial limitations in terms of which parts of the .NET Framework are available.

In addition, keep in mind that Silverlight runs in a sandbox on the client, so it doesn't have access to the local drive, except through IsolatedStorage.

Have you considered using a ClickOnce WPF client instead? That would address both of the issues above.

Comment: I already have a ClickOnce WPF client. I'm trying to port it to an OOB Silverlight app as I have 2 other Silverlight apps I'd like to share code with. The code I need to put in the DLLs is not supported by the Silverlight runtime. Does this mean P/Invoke?

Comment: You can't use P/Invoke from Silverlight, since that would violate the sandbox principle. I've worked on some SL apps where we've implemented our own versions of missing classes -- but that can be a big/near-impossible job, depending on what you're missing. In some cases, it's possible to extract the code you need from the desktop Framework and bundle it with your SL app; but again, it's a potential source of headaches galore.

Comment: Silverlight 5 allows you to P/Invoke with elevated trust. See here http://bit.ly/pBe8z3

Comment: Yes, true enough. If you're willing to go with SL5 and a full-trust app, then you've broken out of the sandbox, and P/Invoke is possible.

Comment: The question is how. I can see plenty of examples on how to use P/Invoke with native DLLs but none on how to use P/Invoke with managed code DLLs. This is the main point of my question.

Comment: I think you would need to make classes in your DAL assembly accessible via COM (see the ComVisible attribute), then use regular COM P/Invoke. I've never done it, though, so I imagine the devil is in the details.